# TIdSMTP Indy10, show me a "Connect timeout" just in Gmail and Windows 11

Tags: windows, delphi, smtp, gmail, indy

Well, i'm try to send a e-mail using TIdSMTP Indy10, but with GMAIL and Windows 11 show a Timeout message, i'm  run te same delphi application in a Windows 10 and works fine.

Anyone did have this issue?

smtp.gmail.com
port:587
Using the google account App password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email via GMail with app specific password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554797/sending-email-via-gmail-with-app-specific-password)

Comment: @EirikA. `Using the google account App password.` - seems an app password is used already. And it is working on one system (on W10).

Comment: The title seems to say that it is not working with GMail and Windows 11. But on both systems (W10 and W11), you are trying to send via GMail, correct?

Comment: Yes, i'm use the same compiled application, in windows 10 and 11, in both i'm trying send a email by gmail, but only in windows 10 is runing with sucess.

Comment: Solved

In my code on the TIdSMTP UseTLS property are did set how utUseRequireTLS, and the Indy on the method SetUseTLS, force the const FRegularProtPort(port 25), then i changed to utUseExplicitTLS, and works fine with Gmail/Windows 11 now.

Comment: @Mateus First, please don't edit a question to say it is solved. Post an actual answer instead. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Please correct that. Second, you should never use `utUseRequireTLS` on the client side, it is meant for server-side use instead.